# Can not get any page after running node server in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io

I uploaded all Node.js related file in Ubuntu server .i opened putty and typed my server's instance ip then started the server after moving to the uploaded file directory.The Node server is running successfully but when i tried to get the pages by typing the url `e.g-*.*.*.*:8888` which contains the server's instance ip and port number no page is coming.It is throwing the message `This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.I am explaining my code and server's snap shot below.

[image: Snap shot]

> server.js:

```
var port=8888;
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var database='Oditek';
var collections=['video'];
var app= express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var db = mongo.connect("10.25.25.100:27017/"+database, collections);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
db.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/login.html');
});
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.userpassword;
    if(username && password){
        db.video.findOne({
            username:username,
            password:password
        },function(err,doc){
            if(doc){
                console.log('login',doc);
                res.send(doc);
            }
            if(err){
                console.log('login12',err);
                res.send("could not login");
            }
        });
    }
});
app.get('/index',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/index.html');
});
app.get('/video',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/video.html');
});
app.get('/whiteboard',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/whiteboard.html');
});
//socket----programming//
var roomid;
var clients={};
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    //console.log('socket id',socket);
    if(socket.handshake.query.roomid){
      roomid=socket.handshake.query.roomid;
    }
    var usertype=socket.handshake.query.usertype;
    //var url=socket.handshake.headers.referer;
    //var myString = url.substr(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
    //var usertype=myString.substr(myString.indexOf("=")+1);
    //console.log('usertype',usertype);
    clients[usertype]={
        "socket":socket.id
    }
    console.log('clients',clients['admin'].socket);
    socket.on('admin-join',function(data){
        if(data.IsJoinAdmin){
            socket.join(roomid);
        }
    });
    socket.on('user-join',function(data){
        console.log('user wants to join',data);
        //console.log('user type',clients);
        if(data.isUserJoin){
            io.sockets.connected[clients[data.usertype].socket].emit('user-already-joined',data);
            socket.join(roomid);
        }
    });
    socket.on('send-playing-video-request-to-users',function(data){
        io.to(roomid).emit('sending-broadcasting',data);
    });
    socket.on('send-broadcasting-message',function(data){
        io.to(roomid).emit('sending-broadcasting',data);
    });
    socket.on('share-white-board',function(msg){
        io.to(roomid).emit('sharing-white-board',msg);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    for(var user in clients) {
        if(clients[user].socket === socket.id) {
            delete clients[user];
            io.to(roomid).emit('user-has-left',{userleft:true});
            break;
        }
    }   
  })

});
server.listen(port);
console.log('server is listening on the port'+port);
```

Here i can not get the pages even if the server is running.Please help me to get the pages after running the node server.

Comment: Is this an AWS server?

Comment: can you ping to that server??

Comment: @trex005:No this is not an Aws server.

Comment: @Subburaj:yes i can ping to that server.

Comment: 2 things. js-bson error with mongo could be an issue. Also, are you trying the open the page from windows? or from your server? Does the code work locally on your machine? We would need more detail to help you.

Comment: @livepo:In my local system this app is nicely running.I am opening the pages in windows but server is running in ubuntu.i did not get any js-bson error messages when i was running in lcal system.

Comment: @livepo: i removed js-bson error but still error is there.